# Maintain context between unit test methods in VS Test Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, automated-tests, mstest

I want to run the following unit tests, in order:

1. Create new customer with a random number for name, password etc.
2. Retrieve the just created customer and assert that its properties contain the same random number
3. Call the ForgotPassword function on same user, with the same random number for user name

As seen clearly, I need to generate a random number once, and share it across 3 test methods.
I cannot seem to find a way to do that.

- I thought of using the TestContext object, but that gets created for each instance.
- I tried Using the ClassInitialize() method doesn't help, as it is static, and therefore the number is not accessible by other methods.

Any idea how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you just place your shared data into static variables?

Something simple like this:

```
    private static string testValue = "something";

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(testValue, "something");
        testValue = "something2";
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(testValue, "something2");
        testValue = "something3";
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(testValue, "something3");
    }
```

Update: To summarize other comments on this question, I think that everyone is in complete agreement that keeping state between unit tests is a bad idea.  My answer was simply a way to do this, if necessary.  As I mentioned in another comment, I have had to do this in the past, but not for unit tests.  It is sometimes beneficial/necessary to keep state between integration/regression tests where you don't necessarily want to mock objects or isolate parts of the application.  As a software tester, you do not always have the influence/ability/permission to immediately refactor or rearchitect an application to be optimal for this testing.

Comment: Not possible. As stated, the value changes randomly every time the test are run. I need a variable, not a constant.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding your question.  It sounded like you wanted to keep some state between multiple unit tests in the same class during a single run.  The code above works as expected with the static variable even changing in the individual test cases.

Comment: No, you understood me well. My mistake - the static variable works. I just can't get the sequence of tests to work. I may have some timing issue (i.e. retrieve needs a delay after create). Guess I must be doing something wrong - I'm using an OrderedList but still it looks like they may be running in parallel.

Comment: I upvoted your answer - I didn't want to look like I was plagarising.  From Traveling's original comment it seemed like your answer didn't work for him since the values assigned wouldn't change between tests, so I added the static constructor.

Comment: The problem with this approach is each test method you write is now dependent on orchestration *outside* the test method in order to pass. This is very very brittle - and you don't want to make testing hard. You're better off loading the data as needed into your test method.

Comment: If you are worried about execution order, you can now create OrderedTests in Visual Studio.  I'm not sure how far back this feature goes but in the latest version of visual studio (2013 preview) it's a valid solution to your order problem.

Comment: This worked great for something I was doing within a unit testing project. I basically use Selenium to perform some basic SEO reporting before major content pushes and these tests build and verify the sitemap for certain things. My first unit test builds the sitemap - a dictionary of URLs that I need to use in later tests to validate specific SEO signals. So just adding a static variable was a great way to solve this little problem.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do here is use something like a Repository behind an IRepository interface:

```
interface IRepository{
    Customer GetCustomer(int id);
}
```

You can implement a real class in your code that will query a database, but in your tests you can "Mock" this interface to return exactly what you want. [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) is my favorite - and what follows is pseudo code but hopefully you'll get the idea:

```
[Test]
public void Customer_Should_Have_CreateAt_Set_To_Today{
  var mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
  mock.Setup(x => x.GetCustomer(100)).Returns(new Customer{id = 100, Name = "Steve"});

  var Customer = mock.Object;
  Assert.Equal(Customer.CreatedAt,Date.Today);
}
```

The idea here is that you control, completely, the data you need to control without relying on when an object is instantiated etc.

Comment: Rob, I don't want to change my original class, nor add another construct, if not necessary. I'd like to use the test class that I already have. I'm also not sure how/if your suggestion helps across several test methods.

Comment: I hear you - the problem is that it makes it difficult to test (as you're finding out). I know it seems like extra work - but the mocking approach works very well and solves the issues as you see here. It's not *supposed to* work across test methods - your tests are (ideally) supposed to be independent in terms of where their data is from, and the isolation they use.

Answer (score 2):

It is a really bad idea to be running unit tests that share context. Although I am open to suggestions, I've never come across a good reason for doing what you are suggesting.

If somebody runs your tests in a different order, or in isolation, then they will fail. Tests like this are termed *flakey* - they pass sometimes, but not others - and it isn't clear why.

It's much better to use a mocking framework like [Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) to instantiate the mock dependencies in the state that you need. That way, each test is a standalone test that verifies a specific thing without reference to any other tests.

You will find it much easier to maintain tests like these, and there'll be fewer false positives and negatives in your results.

Comment: I accept your comment (though I did accept another answer - the one that actually work). I'll re-work my tests to be able to run on their own.

Comment: Good to hear it. Hope it makes your life easier ;-)

Comment: This is certainly the best advice.  Sometimes though I think it comes down to terminology.  I frequently have used VS Unit Testing for driving regression tests.  Sometimes it is beneficial to have some shared state when running these tests.  I certainly try to avoid it, but the alternative is often a complex setup/teardown (that can be the source of failures) or running many tests within one method.  Probably a good rule of thumb is that if your unit test requires state, then it is probably not a unit test.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer - The only shared state that I would use would be constants - for example a username. The complex setup/teardown can be mitigated by using a mocking framework. Isolated tests that each assert one thing, fails or succeed for exactly one reason. The specificity of the test makes it easy to see a problem; trivial to maintain; and you can re-run it (quickly) without reference to any other tests - critical for long-running test suites. Global state was the death of procedural programming - and the XTest frameworks, are often used in a procedural way (1 class has many responsibilities).

Comment: @Xcaliburp - my comment was specific to regression/integration tests (not unit tests) where you don't really want to use a mocking framework or in some cases don't necessarily want to isolate parts of the application.  Your advice is sound and well-taken.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer - Oh, I see now. Some regression tests are complex, but many can benefit from mocking irrelevant areas of the application. However, integration tests are always complicated beasts, which may necessitate more complicated code. Such tests are generally the minority of the test cases. But I accept your point in those cases - needs must! Very much on-topic ;-)

Comment: I agree - I use NSubstitute, however I suggest one exception to this rule - Mocking a DB to test a DAL, its way over the top. I mocked the entire Excel object model using NSubstitute so I know the cost vs value benefit. If your testing CRUD operations and wish to insert a record and persist its @@Identity in order to test retrieval, updating and deletion IMHO 1 private static id variable is better value than mocking.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - I have mixed feeling on this one. Success in automated testing is all about focusing on behaviour. Once we get into the realm of persistent storage, it's going to get messy because a test can pass or fail because an earlier test failed, or because the data in the db is unexpected. In this case, I would tend to break the rule about one assert per test, and create a single test that verified the insert, select, update and then delete aspects. It would be an integration test that could test the lifetime of a particular database entity. It's not ideal, but better than no tests.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad form to build unit tests with dependencies. It is not, however, bad form to build **functional** tests with dependencies. In fact, it's almost required in any application with a normal level of complexity.

What you're trying to do is not a unit test. It's a functional test. And you do need ot share values between test methods to accomplish things from a user's perspective.