# Accessing CurrentTestOutcome in ClassCleanup?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Using C# 4.0. I have a unit test where I need to create a temporary database. This is done during class initialization:

```
[ClassInitialize()]
public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
    // Create database!
}

[ClassCleanup()]
public static void MyClassCleanup()
{
    // Remove database IF CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Passed
}
```

**Q:** How can I read the `CurrentTestOutcome` value from my `ClassCleanup` method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maintain context between unit test methods in VS Test Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976251/maintain-context-between-unit-test-methods-in-vs-test-project)

Comment: Not quite. In this case, the database can be seen as "context between unit test methods". However, when cleaning up, how would you know if all tests were successful? (I don't want to delete the database if a test fails.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm considering the following solution. Not sure if this may be considered good practice or not.

```
private static IList<TestContext> testResults;

public TestContext TestContext
{
    get
    {
        return testContext;
    }
    set
    {
        testContext = value;

        testResults.Add(testContext);
    }
}

[ClassInitialize()]
public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
    testResults = new List<TestContext>();
}

[ClassCleanup()]
public static void MyClassCleanup()
{
    if (testResults.All(t => t.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Passed ||
        t.CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Inconclusive))
    {
        // Perform conditional cleanup!
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do go with this approach, I'd consider saving the TestContext in a TestCleanup, rather than in the setter on the TestContext property.  Doing it after the test has run seems like the right place to do it... but that's just a personal preference.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest that you create a static flag that you can access from your `MyClassCleanup` and set it during test cleanup when you get an error.  Something like the following on your class:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTests {
    static bool _testFailed;

    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        // Create database!
        _testFailed = false;
    }

    [ClassCleanup()]
    public static void MyClassCleanup()
    {
        if(_testFailed == false) {
        // Remove database IF CurrentTestOutcome == UnitTestOutcome.Passed
        }
    }

    [TestCleanup()]
    public void MyTestCleanup() {
        if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome != UnitTestOutcome.Passed) {
            _testFailed = true;
        }
    }

    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

}
```

I'm suggesting the above approach because my understanding is that in your class cleanup, referring to `CurrentTestOutcome` wouldn't really make much since.  It would simply contain the state of the last test to run, not the combined outcome from all of the tests in the class.

Comment: What if you have 10 tests and 9 of them fail, followed by the last one which succeeds? In that case, your code will tell us that the entire class test succeeded.

Comment: @l33t No... it won't.  The flag is set to true as soon as **ANY** test fails.  The flag is static, so will hold it's value through all of the tests.  if **ANY** tests fail, the flag will be set and the database won't be deleted.