# Can I create sequential integration test in Nunit 3 passing parameter between them

Tags: nunit, integration-testing, nunit-3.0

So I want to run first test that creates a object in DB, then I want to pass the id to the next tests in succession that test get,alter,delete. This should ensure the object is deleted at the end.

I know this isn't the preferred method of integration testing against DB, but there are external resources we can't control and this has been requested.

I can't use `TestCaseSource` as later tests wouldn't know if I added anything to it because they are all created before being run.

Comment: Not clear to me what is the issue here? why can't you just keep the id in a static or class member? maybe this one is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976251/maintain-context-between-unit-test-methods-in-vs-test-project

Answer (score 1):

You can create your object in a `OneTimeSetUp` method, saving the id in a private member, and delete it in a `OneTimeTearDown` method. If an exception is thrown in the `OneTimeSetUp`, then none of your tests will be run.

Your get, alter and delete tests should use the `Order` attribute to control what order they are run in and to guarantee that delete is run last. Note that you should also delete the record in `OneTimeTearDown` if it still exists, since exceptions may have prevented the delete test from running.